# Organizing multiple switching characters with health bars in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a 2 player text-based pokemon battle replica with multiple pokemon in it that can be switched out and have their own health and moves.

I have successfully made a similar script where one person fought against the computer where the computer player did basically nothing and there was also only one pokemon per player. Now I am trying to expand on that by making it so that two people can fight each other on the same device, playing hot seat style.

The problem I'm having is that I have yet to find a way to organize and call back each individual pokemon while the players switch around which one is the active one.  I have tried using dictionaries, but they are not very useful when I want to damage the pokemon, because I cannot seem to change the value in each heath bar when using them.  I have not yet tried to make a dictionary for each individual pokemon, just one per player containing them.

But the problem with having individual dictionaries, is that I need a way to tell how many pokemon are left on each team.  There are three per team, and the battle ends when one team is completely wiped out.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'll leave my original Player VS. Computer script here for reference:

```
import time
Hm=150
Hr=60
TackleMove=50
ScratchMove=40
BiteMove=60
#Intro
print 'Difficulty? Type "Easy", "Normal", "Hard"'
EsMo = input("Answer: ")   
print "A wild Magikarp appeared!"
time.sleep(0.5)
print "Go! Rattata!"
time.sleep(0.5)

#Using a move
def PlayerTurn():
    print 'Moves are: "Tackle", "Scratch", "HyperFang", "Bite"'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Move = input("Use: ")
    #Tackle
    if Move is "Tackle":
        print "Rattata used Tackle!"
        global Hm
        Hm-=TackleMove
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if EsMo is "Hard":
            pass
        elif EsMo is "Easy" or "Normal":
            print "Magikarp has", Hm, "HP Left"

    #Scratch
    elif Move is "Scratch":
        print "Rattata used Scratch!"
        Hm-=ScratchMove
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if EsMo is "Hard":
            pass
        elif EsMo is "Easy" or "Normal":
            print "Magikarp has", Hm, "HP Left"

    #HyperFang
    elif Move is "HyperFang":
        print "Rattata used HyperFang!"
        Hm/=2
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if EsMo is "Hard":
            pass
        elif EsMo is "Easy" or "Normal":
            print "Magikarp has", Hm, "HP Left"

    #Bite
    elif Move is "Bite":
        print "Rattata used Bite!"
        Hm-=BiteMove
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if EsMo is "Hard":
            pass
        elif EsMo is "Easy" or "Normal":
            print "Magikarp has", Hm, "HP Left"

    #Cheat
    elif Move is "Cheat":
        print "CHEATER!"
        Hm-=Hm
        print "Magikarp has", Hm, "HP Left"
    else:
        print "Oops"
    return

#AI Turn
def AITurn():
    if Hm>50 or EsMo is "Easy":
        print "Magikarp used Splash!"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "But nothing happened..."
    elif Hm<=50 and EsMo is "Normal" or "Hard":
        print "Magikarp used Tackle!"
        global Hr
        Hr-=TackleMove
        time.sleep(1)
        print "Rattata has", Hr, "HP Left"
    else:
        print "Oops"
    return

#Full Loop
while Hm>0:
    #Action Choice
    print 'Actions are: "Fight", "Pokeball", "Run"'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Action = input("What do you want to do?: ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #If Choose Fight
    if Action is "Fight":
        PlayerTurn()
        if Hm<=0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Magikarp Fainted!"
            time.sleep(1)
            print "You Win!"
            break
        time.sleep(0.5)
        AITurn()
        if Hm<=0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Magikarp Fainted!"
            time.sleep(1)
            print "You Win!"
            break
        elif Hr<=0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Rattata Fainted!"
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print "You Lost!"
            break
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue
    #If Choose Run
    if Action is "Run":
        print "Ran away Safley!"
        break
    #If Choose Pokeball
    if Action is "Pokeball":
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print "You threw the Pokeball!"
        time.sleep(1)
        if Hm>100:
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Darn! It Broke Free!"
        elif 50<Hm<=100:
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Almost had it!"
        elif 30<Hm<=50:
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Shoot! So Close!"
        elif Hm<=30:
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "You Caught a Magikarp!"
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print "Congratulations!"
            break
        else:
            print "Oops"
        time.sleep(1)
        AITurn()
        if Hm<=0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Magikarp Fainted!"
            time.sleep(1)
            print "You Win!"
            break
        elif Hr<=0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Rattata Fainted!"
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print "You Lost!"
            break
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue
time.sleep(2)
print "Please, try again!"
#End
```

My current code is in two forms and is still being worked out so I have some things more complete than others.  In this instance, I only have Rattata's stuff filled out, and the move that I'm testing with is Scratch.

```
import time
P1Rat=50
P1Abra=100
P1Pidgey=100
P2Rat=50
P2Abra=100
P2Pidgey=100
Play1PokeSt=["Rattata", "Abra", "Pidgey"]
ActPl1Poke=[]
ActPl1PokeSt=[]
Play2PokeSt=["Rattata", "Abra", "Pidgey"]
ActPl2Poke=[]
ActPl2PokeSt=[]

#Player 1's Rattata Attacks
def Rattata1():
    global ActPl2Poke
    print 'Moves are: "Tackle", "Scratch", "HyperFang", "Bite"'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    R1Move = input("Use: ")
    #Tackle
    if R1Move is "Tackle":
        print "Rattata used Tackle!"
        ActPl2Poke[0]-=50

    #Scratch
    elif R1Move is "Scratch":
        print "Rattata used Scratch!"
        ActPl2Poke[0]-=40
        print ActPl2Poke[:]
        print P2Rat

    #HyperFang
    elif R1Move is "HyperFang":
        print "Rattata used HyperFang!"
        ActPl2Poke[0]/=2

    #Bite
    elif R1Move is "Bite":
        print "Rattata used Bite!"
        ActPl2Poke[0]-=60

def Play1Sel():
    while True:
        print "What Pokemon do you want to use?"
        print "Remaining Pokemon are:"
        print ", ".join(Play1PokeSt)
        Pokemon1=input()
        if Pokemon1 is "Rattata" and "Rattata" in Play1PokeSt:
            del ActPl1Poke[:]
            ActPl1Poke.append(int(P1Rat))
            del ActPl1PokeSt[:]
            ActPl1PokeSt.append("Rattata")
            break
        elif Pokemon1 is "Rattata" and "Rattata" not in Play1PokeSt:
            print "Rattata has fainted! Choose another!"
            continue
        if Pokemon1 is "Abra" and "Abra" in Play1PokeSt:
            del ActPl1Poke[:]
            ActPl1Poke.append(P1Abra)
            del ActPl1PokeSt[:]
            ActPl1PokeSt.append("Abra")
            break
        elif Pokemon1 is "Abra" and "Abra" not in Play1PokeSt:
            print "Abra has fainted! Choose another!"
            continue
        if Pokemon1 is "Pidgey" and "Pidgey" in Play1PokeSt:
            del ActPl1Poke[:]
            ActPl1Poke.append(P1Pidgey)
            del ActPl1PokeSt[:]
            ActPl1PokeSt.append("Pidgey")
            break
        elif Pokemon1 is "Pidgey" and "Pidgey" not in Play1PokeSt:
            print "Pidgey has fainted! Choose another!"
            continue


def Play2Sel():
    while True:
        print "What Pokemon do you want to use?"
        print "Remaining Pokemon are:"
        print ", ".join(Play2PokeSt)
        Pokemon2=input()
        if Pokemon2 is "Rattata" and "Rattata" in Play2PokeSt:
            del ActPl2Poke[:]
            ActPl2Poke.append(P2Rat)
            del ActPl2PokeSt[:]
            ActPl2PokeSt.append("Rattata")
            break
        elif Pokemon2 is "Rattata" and "Rattata" not in Play2PokeSt:
            print "Rattata has fainted! Choose another!"
            continue
        if Pokemon2 is "Abra" and "Abra" in Play2PokeSt:
            del ActPl2Poke[:]
            ActPl2Poke.append(P2Abra)
            del ActPl2PokeSt[:]
            ActPl2PokeSt.append("Abra")
            break
        elif Pokemon2 is "Abra" and "Abra" not in Play2PokeSt:
            print "Abra has fainted! Choose another!"
            continue
        if Pokemon2 is "Pidgey" and "Pidgey" in Play2PokeSt:
            del ActPl2Poke[:]
            ActPl2Poke.append(P2Pidgey)
            del ActPl2PokeSt[:]
            ActPl2PokeSt.append("Pidgey")
            break
        elif Pokemon2 is "Pidgey" and "Pidgey" not in Play2PokeSt:
            print "Pidgey has fainted! Choose another!"
            continue
#Player 2's Rattata Attacks
def Rattata2():
    global ActPl2Poke
    print 'Moves are: "Tackle", "Scratch", "HyperFang", "Bite"'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    R2Move = input("Use: ")
    #Tackle
    if R2Move is "Tackle":
        print "Rattata used Tackle!"
        ActPl1Poke[0]-=50

    #Scratch
    elif R2Move is "Scratch":
        print "Rattata used Scratch!"
        ActPl1Poke[0]-=40
        print P1Rat


    #HyperFang
    elif R2Move is "HyperFang":
        print "Rattata used HyperFang!"
        ActPl1Poke[0]/=2

    #Bite
    elif R2Move is "Bite":
        print "Rattata used Bite!"
        ActPl1Poke[0]-=60        

#Player 1's Turn
def Play1():
    print "Actions are: Fight, Change"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Act1=input("What do you want to do?: ")
    if Act1 is "Fight" and str(*ActPl1PokeSt) is "Rattata":
        Rattata1()
    elif Act1 is "Change":
        Play1Sel()
    else:
        print "oops"


#Player 2's Turn
def Play2():
    print "Actions are: Fight"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Act2=input("What do you want to do?: ")
    if Act2 is "Fight" and str(*ActPl2PokeSt) is "Rattata":
        Rattata2()
    else:
        print "oops"

#Whole Loop
print "Player 1! Select Your Pokemon!"
Play1Sel()
print ActPl1Poke
print "Player 2! Select Your Pokemon!"
Play2Sel()
print ActPl2Poke
while True:
    print "Player 1, your turn."
    Play1()
    if P1Rat <=0 or P2Rat <=0:
        print "Finish"
        break
    else:
        print "Player 2, your turn."
        Play2()
        if P1Rat <=0 or P2Rat <=0:
            print "Finish"
            break
        continue
```

And then this is the other version:

```
import time

Poke1={"Rattata" : 100 , "Abra" : 100 , "Pidgey" : 100}
Poke2={"Rattata" : 100 , "Abra" : 100 , "Pidgey" : 100}
ActPo1={}
ActPo2={}

#Player 1's Rattata's Moves
def RattataAtk1():
    print 'Moves are: "Tackle", "Scratch", "HyperFang", "Bite"'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    MoveR1 = input("Use: ")
    #Tackle
    if MoveR1 is "Tackle":
        print "Rattata used Tackle!"
        ActPo2-=50

    #Scratch
    elif MoveR1 is "Scratch":
        print "Rattata used Scratch!"
        ActPo2-=40

    #HyperFang
    elif MoveR1 is "HyperFang":
        print "Rattata used HyperFang!"
        ActPo2/=2   

    #Bite
    elif MoveR1 is "Bite":
        print "Rattata used Bite!"
        ActPo2-=60

#Player 2's Rattata's Moves
def RattataAtk2():
    print 'Moves are: "Tackle", "Scratch", "HyperFang", "Bite"'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    MoveR2 = input("Use: ")
    #Tackle
    if MoveR2 is "Tackle":
        print "Rattata used Tackle!"
        ActPo1-=50

    #Scratch
    elif MoveR2 is "Scratch":
        print "Rattata used Scratch!"
        ActPo1-=40

    #HyperFang
    elif MoveR2 is "HyperFang":
        print "Rattata used HyperFang!"
        ActPo1/=2   

    #Bite
    elif MoveR2 is "Bite":
        print "Rattata used Bite!"
        ActPo1-=60


#Selection of Player 1's Pokemon
def Play1Sel():
    while True:
        print "What Pokemon do you want to use?"
        print "Remaining Pokemon are:"
        print Poke1.keys()
        Choose1=input()
        if Choose1 is "Rattata" and "Rattata" in Poke1:
            ActPo1["Rattata"]=Poke1["Rattata"]
            break
        else:
            print "Oops"
            break

#Selection of Player 2's Pokemon
def Play2Sel():
    while True:
        print "What Pokemon do you want to use?"
        print "Remaining Pokemon are:"
        print Poke2.keys()
        Choose2=input()
        if Choose2 is "Rattata" and "Rattata" in Poke2:
            ActPo2["Rattata"]=Poke2["Rattata"]
            break
        else:
            print "Oops"
            break

#Player 1's Choice of Action
def Play1():
    print "Actions are: Fight, Change"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Act1=input("What do you want to do?: ")
    if Act1 is "Fight" and ActPo1.has_key("Rattata") is True:
        RattataAtk1()
    else:
        print "Oops"

#Player 2's Choice of Action
def Play2():
    print "Actions are: Fight, Change"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Act2=input("What do you want to do?: ")
    if Act2 is "Fight" and ActPo2.has_key("Rattata") is True:
        RattataAtk2()
    else:
        print "Oops"

#Full Loop
print "Player 1! Select Your Pokemon!"
Play1Sel()
print ActPo1.items()
print "Player 2! Select Your Pokemon!"
Play2Sel()
print ActPo2.items()
while True:
    print "Player 1, your turn."
    Play1()
    if ActPo1.values()is 0:
        print "Finish"
        break
    else:
        print "Player 2, your turn."
        Play2()
        if ActPo2.values()is 0:
            print "Finish"
            break
        continue
```

Comment: take a look at lists, they would help you decrease the repetition in your code. similarly, each player's pokemon should be stored in a list, so you can modify the health etc. as you need to. also, please post the code that isn't working; the code that works is of no use to anyone trying to help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I'll look into it.  I just posted my current code in the main question if you want to look at it.

Comment: Yeah, just made modifications to my code and lists were definitely the way to go!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Did you end up figuring out the problems with the dictionaries?

Comment: It actually was the dictionaries themselves.  Lists were what I needed to make the code work, so I basically switched all my dictionaries over to lists, with a couple of other changes, and my code works great now.

Comment: I'd typed up my answer but forgot about it. It explains why dictionaries didn't work for you. Glad you found a solution though :)

Answer (score 0):

## Syntax or Functional Errors

I quickly skimmed your code:

`ActPo2-=50`: you can't do math on a dictionary. I think you mean

```
current_pokemon = "Rattata"
ActPo2[current_pokemon] -= 50
```

`is`: This operator doesn't do what you think, it compares the values in memory.

```
h = "hello"
h is "hello" # False 
h == "hello" # True
```

Also, `ActPo1.values() is 0` will never be true, because `ActPo1.values()` returns a list. You probably mean `len(ActPo1)`